# Draw, then re-draw lines in python code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a python beginner trying to draw a bunch of points and a line on a plot using the matplotlib.pyplot library. Below is some sample code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x1,x2,n,m,b = -50.,150.,11,0.,0.
x = np.r_[x1:x2:n*1j]
for list in points:
        plt.plot(list[0], list[1], 'rs')     
plt.axis([ -50, 150, -50, 150])
plt.plot(x, m*x + b)
plt.show()
```

What i am looking to do is re-draw objects on the same plot. Like for example the line i drew, i would like to redraw it with a different m and b say after 1/2 second. Could anyone suggest some code changes to do the same?

Comment: Do you want the old line to be retained or it to be cleared off ?

Comment: what is `points` here?

Comment: 1.) Old line should not be retained. 2.) points is just a bunch if points data from a file. That part works fine, and i see red points drawn on screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to enter interactive mode with `plt.ion()`, plot your line and store it and then change its ydata

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
x1,x2,n,m,b = -50.,150.,11,0.,0.
x = np.r_[x1:x2:n*1j]
plt.ion()
plt.axis([ -50, 150, -50, 150])
line, = plt.plot(x, m*x + b)    # comma is needed because plot returns a tuple
for m in np.r_[1:0:-0.1]:
    line.set_ydata(m*x + b)
    plt.draw()
    sleep(0.5)
```